# Why can std::get() not be used to get members of a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I am confused about the `std::get()` function. `std::get()` can be used to access members in `array`, `pair`, and `tuple`. So, why does the Standard not also allow it to access the members in `vector`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility> // std::pair
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    array<int, 4> a1{3,4,5,67};
    pair<int,int>  p1{5,6};
    tuple<int,float,float> t1{6,5.5,4.5};

    cout << std::get<1>(a1) <<endl;
    cout << std::get<1>(p1) <<endl;
    cout << std::get<1>(t1) <<endl;
}
```

Following is the output:

```
4
6
5.5
```

But when I try to use `std::get()` with `vector`, I get this compilation error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility> // std::pair
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 vector<int> v1{4,5,6,7,9};
 cout << std::get<1>(v1) <<endl;
}
```

Compilation error:

```
  main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
  main.cpp:10:27: error: no matching function for call to 'get(std::vector&)'
  cout << std::get<1>(v1) <<endl;
                       ^
  In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
 /usr/include/c++/5/array:280:5: note: candidate: template constexpr _Tp& 
  std::get(std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&)
  get(array<_Tp, _Nm>& __arr) noexcept
  ^
```

Comment: An `std::array` and an `std::pair` both model a tuple: a fixed-size collection of possibly heterogeneous objects. But a `std::vector` is not fixed-size.

Comment: I don't see why we couldn't have one but it was probably not put in since `vector` is not a compile time construct.  `std::pair`, `std::tuple` and `std::array` are all sized at compile time and used in TMP.  A vector is sized at run time and cannot be used in TMP.

Comment: I was completely unaware that `std::get` worked on `std::array`!

Comment: std::get can also be used with variant

Comment: @OrçunÇolak [*Excellent* point!](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get) That seems to dramatically undercut the answers about its main benefit being compile-time checking, since the active member of a `variant` can only be checked at runtime.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`std::get`'s index being a template parameter allows it to check at compile time whether the index is valid. This is only possible when the container's size is known at compile time too. `std::vector` has a variable size: you can add or remove elements at run time. This means `std::get` for vectors would offer zero benefits over `operator[]` or `at`.

Comment: the templated nature of `std::get` also allows it to return different types for different indexes (used in `pair` and `tuple`) which is also not a benefit for `vector`

Comment: @vu1p3n0x True, but that's also not a benefit for `std::array`, which does get a `std::get`.

Comment: There is a movement towards creating a compile time version of std::vector (in which case this might have a place in the future) - see for example https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/sg14/PYu_mBeAlrk